# angular load data in component only when indexedDb table is populated

Tags: javascript, angular, indexeddb

In my service I have this:

```
  synchronizeCitiesOnLogin() {
    ....
    this.getCitiesFromApi().subscribe(
      cities => {
        cities.map((city) => {
            this.addCityToIndexedDb(city);
        });
      }
    );
  }
  getCitiesFromApi() {
    ....
    return this.apiClient.get(url, { })
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => response.data ),
        catchError(errorRes => {
          return throwError(errorRes);
        })
      );
  }
  addCitiesToIndexedDb(city) {
    this.cityTable
      .add(city)
      .then(async () => {
        const allItems: CityModel[] = await this.cityTable.toArray();
      })
      .catch(e => {
        alert('Error: ' + (e.stack || e));
      });
  }
    getData(): Promise<any> {
        return this.getDataFromIndexedDb()
    }
    private async getDataFromIndexedDb() {
       ...
       ... 
       return mydata
    }
```

In my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getData().then(data => {
      this.worldCities= data;
    });
}
```

Because I have a lot of data that I receive from the API it will take some time to save all of them in the IndexedDB. And when I load the page the "fruits" object will be empty because the data were not saved yet in the IndexedDB ...
It's working if I'm adding a settimeout with 2-3 seconds but for sure it should be a better way to solve it
Can somebody help me with this ?
Thank you

Comment: Can you show us when this method has been called: `synchronizeCitiesOnLogin`?

Comment: login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
  .....
        return this.http.post<any>(url, body, HTTP_OPTIONS)
            .pipe(
              tap(res => {
                this.tokenService.saveToken(res.access_token);
    ...
                this.myService.synchronizeCitiesOnLogin();
              }),
              catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }

Comment: when a user login with succes then I call the synchronizeCitiesOnLogin but he is redirected to the homepage where "this.worldCities" will be empty because the indexedDb is still empty ...

Comment: could be a good approach to recall this.myService.getData().then(data => { this.worldCities= data; }); in my component, until I receive data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider adding a `BehaviorSubject` to `myService`.

```
private synchronized$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

Thereafter you need to somehow catch the completion of cities insertion into indexeddb, with something looking propably like

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

synchronizeCitiesOnLogin() {
  this.getCitiesFromApi().pipe(
    switchMap((cities) => combineLatest(
      cities.map(city => from(this.cityTable.add(city)))
    )),
    tap(() => {
      this.synchronized$.next(true);
    })
  ).subscribe()
}
```

And then you can ensure data is synchronized before accessing it by doing:

```
 getData(): Promise<any> {
    return this.synchronized$.pipe(
      filter(synchronized => synchronized),
      first(),
      switchMap(() => from(this.getDataFromIndexedDb()))
    ).toPromise();
 }
```

The above could certainly be made more readable, as I would strongly suggest to go full `RxJs`, to avoid constantly switching between observables and promise api, by using [ngx-indexed-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db).

Comment: this is working. super thanks